# Make sure file name doesn't go out of scope

Tags: c++, qt, filenames

I would like to choose a file and store the file name as a `char *` member variable of my QT form. I've got the following

```
void MainWindow::SelectVolFile(){
    QString qFileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, 
        tr("Select VOL file..."), QDir::currentPath(), tr("Files (*.VOL)"));
    if (!qFileName.isEmpty()){
        QByteArray byteFileName = qFileName.toLatin1();
        this->fileName = byteFileName->data();
    }
}
```

However, I think once this function returns, `byteFileName->data()` goes out of scope. What's a good way to fix this situation? I'm not sure which variable I should be putting on the heap.

Comment: Well, you don't even need it once the function is done with. Later on, you will get it using this->filename

Comment: What type is `this->fileName`?

Comment: Why not copy it to your member variable then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It heavily depends on `this->fileName`. If `fileName` is a `char*`, then you're right: `byteFileName` goes out of scope and `byteFileName->data()` will be deallocated, which leads to a dangling pointer, `this->fileName`.

The easiest way to fix such a situation is to set the type of `this->fileName` to `QString`, `std::string` or another type that actually copies the content of `byteFileName->data()`.

Comment: You're right, I originally had `fileName` as a `char *`. I guess setting it to a `QString` solves my problem. But out of curiosity, how can I do it with a `char *`? I don't know the exact length of the file name, so what should I allocate on the heap?

Comment: You can get it `strlen(byteFileName->data())`

Comment: Ashot: you mean strdup(byteFileName->data()).
But with this solution one must remember to free this->fileName in destructor.

Comment: @RafałPrzemysławMalinowski: Nonsense. *"I don't know the exact length of the file name"* --> `strlen`, which is part of the standard, while `strdup` isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can define `this->filename` as `QString` and it will work.

If you want to use `char*` for filename, you should use `new` to allocate memory in that function and copy `byteFileName->data()` to it.

```
this->filename = new char[strlen(byteFileName->data())+1];
strcpy(this->filename, byteFileName->data());
```

Answer (score 0):

For the best, do not convert qFileName to anything else (fileName field must be changed to QString):

```
void MainWindow::SelectVolFile(){
    QString qFileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, 
        tr("Select VOL file..."), QDir::currentPath(), tr("Files (*.VOL)"));
    if (!qFileName.isEmpty()){
        this->fileName = qFileName;
    }
}
```

With your code you will not be able to properly handle files with name containing characters outside of latin1 charset.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I can think of three possible solutions:

- copy the object
- use reference counting
- move the object

I would pick the one that is the easiest to use with the given library.